# Filter exactly matched windows services using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to filter out the windows services using PowerShell

Following are the windows services that we have:

```
service_1_UAT
service_UAT
service_2_UAT
service_3_UAT
service_1_Blue_UAT
```

If I do service_*_UAT
it is giving complete service list but service_UAT. But I want the following four:

```
service_1_UAT
service_UAT
service_2_UAT
service_3_UAT
```

and If I give `service_*_Blue_UAT`
 it is giving correct result.

is there any way we can filter out these services using PowerShell Regex ? 
Can someone please suggest me how do I filter.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use 'DataGenerator_?_UAT' as a mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like all service names *actually* match DataGenerator_*_UAT pattern (in names like DataGenerator_1_Blue_UAT substring "1_Blue" matches *, too).

You can use [Where-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx) filter with a regexp. Assuming that by * you mean anything except underscores (_):

```
Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "^DataGenerator_([^_]+_)?UAT$" }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I don't have any powershell code. I'm doing 'DataGenerator_*_UAT'

Comment: Hi Kel, I have updated my question properly. Actually I also have a service called `DataGenerator_UAT` . is there any way we can get `DataGenerator_UAT` services.

Comment: Thanks Kel. But somehow it is not working as expected. Can you please verify the command again ?Thank you

Comment: Hi Mahesh, I tested this command - it should return 4 services you listed in your question: DataGenerator_1_UAT, DataGenerator_UAT, DataGenerator_2_UAT, DataGenerator_3_UAT